# Capture initial amount of Created paypal recurring payment on Capture Api call

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

in my application required feature like create paypal recurring with some initial amount.
  For exa.

```
  Initial Payment          : $300.00 AUD  
  Regular Recurring Payment: $300.00 AUD
```

i have create `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` with specific detail for initial payment and my code.

```
private void populateRequest(CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestType request, string token)
{
            CurrencyCodeType currency = (CurrencyCodeType)
               Enum.Parse(typeof(CurrencyCodeType), "AUD");
            CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetailsType profileDetails =
                new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetailsType();
            request.CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails = profileDetails;
            profileDetails.Token = token;

            var startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T00:00:00:000Z";
            RecurringPaymentsProfileDetailsType rpProfileDetails = new RecurringPaymentsProfileDetailsType(startDate); //MMDDYYYY
            profileDetails.RecurringPaymentsProfileDetails = rpProfileDetails;
            rpProfileDetails.SubscriberName = "Lalji Dhameliya";
            ScheduleDetailsType scheduleDetails = new ScheduleDetailsType();
            scheduleDetails.Description = "Recurring Payment Description";
            int frequency = 1;
            BasicAmountType paymentAmount = new BasicAmountType(currency, "300.00");
            BillingPeriodType period = BillingPeriodType.MONTH;
            int numCycles = 3;
            BillingPeriodDetailsType paymentPeriod = new BillingPeriodDetailsType(period, frequency, paymentAmount);
            paymentPeriod.TotalBillingCycles = numCycles;

            var activationDetails = new ActivationDetailsType();
            activationDetails.InitialAmount = new BasicAmountType(currency, "300.00");
            scheduleDetails.ActivationDetails = activationDetails;
            scheduleDetails.PaymentPeriod = paymentPeriod;
            profileDetails.ScheduleDetails = scheduleDetails;
 }
```

i have set

```
 var paymentDetails = new PaymentDetailsType();
 paymentDetails.PaymentAction = PaymentActionCodeType.AUTHORIZATION;
```

that basic authorization subject to settlement with PayPal Authorization and Capture.

when i create `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` with success but initial payment was capture when profile was created.

is there any way to

> capture initial payment when i call capture api of paypal.

i have search on google and find but all solution are not capture initial payment after sometime.

[image]